# Object-oriented design implementation of an Elevator

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented

I am a newbie when it comes to Object Oriented Programming and I have read a lot of online articles and lessons so I want to try it out on my own. I've written a console app in C# and tried implementing Object Oriented Design and SOLID Principles.

The console app checks if a person has an access to a certain floor. Also, The app is in its initial stage so right now the Elevator accomodates a single person.

Although the app works. any feedback,comments, and suggestions will be greatly appreciated especially in terms of SOLID principles or OOP Design.

here is the code below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person maintenanceEmployee = new MaintenanceEmployee();
        Elevator elev = new Elevator(maintenanceEmployee);
        elev.GoToFloor(Floors.FourthFloor);

        Person guest = new Guest();
        Elevator elev2 = new Elevator(guest);
        elev2.GoToFloor(Floors.SecondFloor);

        Person empfromthirdfloor = new EmployeeFromThirdFloor();
        Elevator elev3 = new Elevator(empfromthirdfloor);
        elev2.GoToFloor(Floors.ThirdFloor);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public enum Floors
{
    FirstFloor = 1,
    SecondFloor = 2,
    ThirdFloor = 3,
    FourthFloor = 4,
    FifthFloor = 5
}



public class Elevator
{
    Person person;
    public Elevator(Person _person)
    {
        this.person = _person;
    }

    public void GoToFloor(Floors _floor)
    {
        if (person.HasAccess(_floor))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elevating to " + _floor.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Access to " + _floor.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Person
{
    public Floors[] accessibleFloors;

    public bool HasAccess(Floors _floor)
    {
        foreach (Floors i in accessibleFloors)
        {
            if (_floor == i)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class MaintenanceEmployee : Person
{
    public Floors[] _accessibleFloors = { Floors.FirstFloor, Floors.SecondFloor, Floors.ThirdFloor, Floors.FourthFloor, Floors.FifthFloor };

    public MaintenanceEmployee()
    {
        //Not sure if this is the best practice
        //Reason why I did it like this is because
        //I need to change the arrays of accessibleFloors
        //in the abstract class "Person" in order to run successfully
        base.accessibleFloors = _accessibleFloors;
    }
}

public class EmployeeFromThirdFloor : Person
{
    public Floors[] _accessibleFloors = { Floors.ThirdFloor };

    public EmployeeFromThirdFloor()
    {
        //Not sure if this is the best practice
        //Reason why I did it like this is because
        //I need to change the arrays of accessibleFloors
        //of the abstract class "Person" in order to run successfully
        base.accessibleFloors = _accessibleFloors;
    }
}

public class Guest : Person
{
    public Floors[] _accessibleFloors = { Floors.SecondFloor };

    public Guest()
    {
        //Not sure if this is the best practice
        //Reason why I did it like this is because
        //I need to change the arrays of accessibleFloors
        //of the abstract class "Person" in order to run successfully
        base.accessibleFloors = _accessibleFloors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume an elevator can at most contain 1 person?

Comment: Please add a description about what you application does. _Elevator Sample_ is too general.

Comment: @dfwze well for now this is just its initial design, at this stage I just like to know if the coding is on track in terms of OOP or SOLID.

Answer (score 4):

#### Person + Derived Classes

- `accessibleFloors` is a breach of *Open–closed principle*. Anyone is able to modify this collection.
- `accessibleFloors` could be considered a breach of *Single responsibility principle*. Consider having a `Role` class and `Person` storing his `Roles` set. This way, you can also mitigate redundant code and remove the need of derived classes as `EmployeeFromThirdFloor`, `Guest` and `MaintenanceEmployee` (in this trivial example these classes are not required).
- `accessibleFloors` can be `null`. The code is not able to handle this situation.
- `HasAccess` is way to convoluted: `accessibleFloors.Contains(_floor);` would do it.

> ```
> public abstract class Person
> {
>     public Floors[] accessibleFloors;
>
>     public bool HasAccess(Floors _floor)
>     {
>         foreach (Floors i in accessibleFloors)
>         {
>             if (_floor == i)
>             {
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```

We can create a class `Role`.

```
public class Role 
{
    public HashSet<Floors> AccessibleFloors { get; }

    public Role (HashSet<Floors> accessibleFloors) 
    {
        AccessibleFloors = accessibleFloors 
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessibleFloors));
    }

    public bool HasAccess(Floor floor)
    { 
        return AccessibleFloors.Contains(floor);
    }

    // override equals and gethashcode ..
}
```

We can refactor `Person`.

```
public class Person
{
    public HashSet<Role> Roles { get; }

    public Person(HashSet roles) {
        Roles = roles ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roles));
    }

    public bool HasAccess(Floors floor)
    {
        return Roles.Any(r => r.HasAccess(floor));
    }
}
```

Because of *Inheritance*, the derived classes do not require to create their own instance variable `_accessibleFloors`.

> `base.accessibleFloors = _accessibleFloors;`

---

#### Elevator

- There is tight-coupling between an `Elevator` and a `Person`. You force the elevator to exist only with a person. What about an empty elevator?
- `GoToFloor` is not usable code. Consider returning a `Boolean` and putting the `Console.WriteLine` in the calling code.
- The code cannot handle when `Person` is `null`.

> ```
> public class Elevator
> {
>     Person person;
>     public Elevator(Person _person)
>     {
>         this.person = _person;
>     }
>
>     public void GoToFloor(Floors _floor)
>     {
>         if (person.HasAccess(_floor))
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Elevating to " + _floor.ToString());
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("No Access to " + _floor.ToString());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

`Elevator` could be refactored as follows.

```
public class Elevator
{
    public Person Person { get; private set; }

    public bool IsFull => Person != null;
    public bool IsEmpty => Person == null;

    public bool Enter(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));
        if (IsFull) return false;
        Person = person;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Exit(Floors floor)
    {
        if (IsEmpty) return false;
        if (!Person.HasAccess(floor)) return false;
        Person = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

#### Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var guestRoles = new HashSet<Role> { 
            new Role(new HashSet<Floors> { Floors.FirstFloor }) 
        };
        var guest = new Person(guestRoles);
        var elevator = new Elevator();
        
        if (elevator.Enter(guest)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guest has entered elevator");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guest cannot enter elevator: elevator is full");
        }

        if (elevator.Exit(Floors.FirstFloor)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guest has exited elevator at FirstFloor");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guest cannot exit elevator at FirstFloor: access is denied");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, I appreciate the remodelling and refactoring of the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If I may add a single consideration to dfhwze's thorough answer:

Having an enum defining floors is OK for a building with 5 floors, but would be overwhelming if we are talking [Burj Khalifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burj_Khalifa) with its 163 floors. Besides that it is a rather rigid concept having a predefined number of floors - supposed you want to reuse your object model for other buildings.

Therefore I would create a `Floor` class too:

```
public class Floor
{
  private Floor(string name, int index)
  {
     Name = name;
     Index = index;
  }

  public string Name { get; }
  public int Index { get; }

  public static IEnumerable<Floor> CreateFloors(params string[] names)
  {
    return names.Select((n, i) => new Floor(n, i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To model Elevator better, you may have following two options:

1. Singleton class Elevator which has existence independent of Person.
2. Rename Elevator to ElevatorTrip. This way ElevatorTrip can exist without
   Person.